# How to plot horizontal and vertical graphs in same plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to visualize the number of black pixels in a binarized image file  with a graph on top of the actual image using matplotlib. Here is the image:
[image: sample.png]

I have managed to count the pixels both vertically (`x_counts`) and horizontally (`y_counts`). What I couldn't still figure out is how to transpose the values of `y_counts`, so that the y_counts-graph aligns as nicely with the image as the `x_counts`.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img_file = "sample.png"
img = mpimg.imread(img_file)

#Count black pixels on x- and y-axis
x_counts = np.sum(img==0, axis=0)
y_counts = np.sum(np.transpose(img)==0, axis=0)

print(y_counts)
input()

#Show image
plt.imshow(img)

#Show number of pixels
plt.plot(x_counts)
plt.plot(y_counts) ### Problem: Graph as to be transposed
plt.show()
```

What I get is:

[image: Figure_1.png]

But I would like to rotate the orange graph 90° counterclockwise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try `plt.plot(y_counts,range(len(y_counts)))`

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html